# Bootstrap Table - can I use json from php variable - not from file?

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap

Official way:

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-url="data2.json" data-sort-name="name">
```

In my case it's bad idea to have json as file - it's our dynamic response.

Any solutions?

Comment: As long as the response is JSON formatted, it doesn't matter if the file is static, or dynamically generated on server side.

Comment: This json from second server..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the id of your table element is "table-id"

```
$('#table-id').bootstrapTable(
      {data: JSON_data}
         );
});
```